# How Can I Easily Tell Which Changelist I'm Integratingin Perforce/P4V?

Tags: perforce, p4v

Sometimes, when I'm using P4V using the `"Merge/Integrate Using Changelist XXX"` option, I get interrupted before I do the actual resolve. If I have a number of integrates on the go at once, I may not remember which specific changelist I was doing.

If I open the Merge Tool, it will tell me the file and version numbers that I am integrating, but this takes a number of clicks.

Is there a simple option to see Pending Changelist X is an integrate of Submitted Changelist Y ?

Comment: The reason for wanting this, is just so I can double check the pending changelists I have open with my local records of what needs integrating. I could populate the pending changelists comments, when do Merge/Integrate

Comment: There isn't a simple option for this; you'll probably want to write a custom tool.  Here's a very simple starting point (only works for unresolved files; you'd need to add a couple more lines to handle files that have already been resolved):

    p4 -Ztag -F "%fromFile%#>%startFromRev%,#%endFromRev%" resolve -n | p4 -x - changes